libc6 dependency mismatch
I've created a Frankenstein's monster by adding Kali stuff to my source list like mentioned in this guide: https://medium.com/@sany4sec/how-to-install-kali-linux-tools-in-ubuntu-or-linux-mint-b2ce8453964e
That worked "fine" but I now get the following error when running apt upgrade:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libc-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.36) but 2.37-12 is installed
libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.35-0ubuntu3.6) but 2.37-12 is installed
         Depends: libc-dev-bin (= 2.35-0ubuntu3.6)

libc6-dev-i386 : Depends: libc6-i386 (= 2.35-0ubuntu3.6) but 2.37-12 is installed
libc6-dev-x32 : Depends: libc6-dev-i386 (= 2.37-12) but 2.35-0ubuntu3.6 is installed
             Depends: libc6-dev (= 2.37-12) but 2.35-0ubuntu3.6 is installed

locales : Depends: libc-bin (> 2.37)
I have disabled the Kali stuff in source.list and tried sudo apt update, sudo apt upgrade but the error persists. Basically, I can't upgrade anything and would like to revert this. How can I rid my system of anything 2.37.-12?
Just to confirm, sudo apt --fix-broken install does NOT work in this case. Help please...I promise I will never try to create a Frankenstein again! :/

Rather than "adding the Kali repositories", why not install the penetration tools from Ubuntu repositories, or from source? Simply installing Kali tools does not make you a penetration tester or a computer security expert.

The Kali version of the package is newer than the Ubuntu version, so apt upgrade thinks the Kali version is preferable. You need to tell APT to do a downgrade. The way to do that is through preferences: raise the priority of Ubuntu packages enough so that they're preferred to installed packages even if the installed packages have a newer version number. Put this in /etc/apt/preferences (and remove it once the downgrade is over):
# Downgrade back to Ubuntu
Package: *
Pin: release o=Ubuntu
Pin-Priority: 1000

You may need something else in addition to or instead of o=Ubuntu, maybe o=Ubuntu,a=jammy*. Run apt-cache policy to see the “release” tags for each of your package sources. You need a pattern that matches all the official Ubuntu sources.
Note that this solves the problem as far as the package manager is concerned. It will attempt to downgrade all the packages. Whether it succeeds depends on the packages themselves. Most packages don't support downgrades, so you may run into errors in their installation/removal scripts, or you may get your system into a state that wasn't quite expected.
For future reference, beware that Kali attracts a lot of people who don't know what they're doing. Given that Kali is intended for professionals, not for beginners, this is a recipe for disaster. I strongly recommend ignoring any blog post or similar about Kali Linux itself (as opposed to a post demonstrating the use of some tool that is conveniently packaged by Kali, and incidentally suggesting to use it via Kali).

To install a specific older version of a package that's available in your configured repositories, you could specify version numbers in the format apt-get install package=version
In your case, resolving the immediately presented issues would then look like:
$ sudo apt-get install libc6=2.35-0ubuntu3.6 libc-bin=2.35-0ubuntu3.6 libc6-dev=2.35-0ubuntu3.6 libc-dev-bin=2.35-0ubuntu3.6 libc6-dev-i386=2.35-0ubuntu3.6 libc6-dev-x32=2.35-0ubuntu3.6 locales=2.35-0ubuntu3.6

There may be other issues that surface once those are resolved - depending on your desire to tweak around, you may find that simply backing up your home directory and reinstalling is easier.
Also, if you want to try out tools designed specifically for use with another distribution's core packages, Distrobox can be an option there. Or, if you simply want to try out another distribution in total, GNOME Boxes provides a very easy interface for that.

Thanks...and yeah, that just lead to other issues. Decided to do a fresh install instead since all my stuff is updated including config files, which was probably way quicker than fixing all the underlying issues of my Frankenstein. Lesson learned, no more mixing of distros.

You might want to take a look at what Kali has to say about using their repositories on a non-Kali system. The short version is "don't do it". I'd recommend taking their advice over that of an unverified web page.
Kali also provides container images that would let you use their tools without affecting your OS.
And just as an FYI, Kali is recommended only for penetration testers experienced with Linux.
